# ckeditor with spring mvc not working

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate ckeditor with a spring mvc project and it does not seem to be working. As far as I can tell I'm following the documentation but something is wrong. The only output I get is a textarea with no toolbar or anything resembling ckeditor. This stays the same if I specify the "Full' toolbar.  It appears as if ckeditor is not being found, but why?

Note: in my servlet-context.xml I have tried both

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and

```
<resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

and still not found.

1) I have ckeditor 3.6.6 in Eclipse under the webapp directory. I copied all the files from the download.

2) My jsp has the following:

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
 </head>
```

note: I've also tried referring to the src as src="/resources/ckeditor/..." but still no go.

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
<br>


 <script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
    {
        toolbar : 'Basic',
        uiColor : '#9AB8F3'
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: can you load your page in Google Chrome and look at the console? Check first to see if any of your references are 404ing.

Comment: Good idea! Yes the ckeditor references are 404ing. I'm also getting CKEDITOR not defined, but that's to be expected. Not sure why ckeditor is not being found.

Comment: It looks in your question like you're reference path to the ckeditor in the `src` is wrong. Make sure that your file/folder structure and reference is correct. Alternatively (see my answer) you can use a CDN.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm not trying to update anything yet. I just want to see the fully functioning ckeditor on my web page.

Comment: I edited my comment and added an answer.

Comment: I've edited again, I think I understand your issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest that you check your reference paths.

Your current path says that the ckeditor.js file should be located at `http://example.com/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` but I'm assuming that it's within a `resources` folder.

Try This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I've posted another answer on how referencing resources should work. This should help you figure out why it's 404ing
[How to properly reference local resources in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14489018/124069)

Alternatively, you can try the CDN hosted file.
*however: there's no guarantee that jsdelivr will be online long term*

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ckeditor/4.0.1/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also note, there are more plugins and such in the cdn
http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!ckeditor

Comment: That was it Chase! Thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that forward slash myself. This is what happens when you copy code while thinking about other problems.