# HTML script src - Jquery library won't load from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socket.io, lan

I'm trying to run the Socket.io example program offline. The index.html page calls the Jquery library like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

However, this obviously won't load without an internet connection. I have tried using a file in the same folder as the rest of the project:

```
 <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

But I get a 404 error in the developer menu when running that as well. I'm not sure if I'm putting the file in the wrong spot, or if I'm using the script tag incorrectly, Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: 
Here is the full index.html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Picture of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K6oB.png)

[Picture of index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaulG.png)

Comment: Will show you were it is trying to get it from..what is different than where it should be looking?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the directory structure of your project. Also include which folder the jquery.js file is located in. This will allow us to tell you the exact path to use in your <script> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I recommend changing your index.js to server.js, it makes more sense that is more like a server file for your app.  It will serve a lot more things not just the index page.  However, you can name it whatever you want. :)

Your problem is that node does not know your file system.  You send the index back with __dirname +/index.html.  __dirname tells node the current directory but on your index file, script src on your index.html file does not know where to start.

On your index.js file, tell node where to get all the static files, between line 3 and 5 app this.

```
app.use('/s', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

the '/s' is the alias for this static directory that we're going to define.  __dirname is your root dirctory and '/static' is the folder where i want all my static files to be since i don't want to expose my whole root.

For that exact line to work, you will need to add a folder name "static" on the directory where your index.js and index.html is right now.

on your index.html file, instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

change the src to "/s/jquery.js" since node.js now knows what alias s represents.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="/s/javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

good luck

Comment: meaning you don't have your jquery file in the right location.  make sure the file name is correct.  can you paste the url that you are looking at and the url of the 404 errors and your file name of your jquery library

Comment: I just added a screenshot with the errors and a picture of the files

Comment: we're getting closer. :) you have a node js file (i believe you named it index.js) that map the index file right?  if so, are you using express in node?

Comment: Yes I am using express

Comment: ok, your problem you're using a node server.  When you send back the index file, node doesn't know what's it's map to and it can't see the directory where the index file is.  try app.use('/') - this will map your whole server which is not recommended.  create a directory where you want to host your static file and do app.use(express.static(path.to.directory));

Comment: try app.use('/') first and if it works, you know what your problem is, then you can restructure. :)

Comment: no, in you server.js file.  but i think you called it index.js file, this is where you tell node to server the index.  right now to start, do you do node index.js in terminal to start???

Comment: Yes to start the server I do node index.js.

Comment: I added a picture of the index.js file

Comment: before line 5 in your index.js.  do app.use("/")

Answer (score 0):

If your Html and JS file are both in the same folder it should work definitely. Otherwise you need to put an address relative to your current file. Say your JS file is in the parent folder of your HTML file then :

```
<script src="../jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: That didn't work either, is the file incorrectly placed?

Comment: Ok ,so could you please copy/paste the exact URL or the both HTML and JS files on your local machine?

Comment: I just added a new screenshot

Comment: OK,as you see your jquery JS file's name is jquery.js so you need to use this address :  <script src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: And for the socketio client JS you need to use this address (according to your folder structure) :
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>

Comment: That part hasn't thrown any errors though? I'll try just in case

Comment: Wierd! you're probably missing something. If the Jquery.js contains the actual jquery library's code and your html file is the index.html then <script src="jquery.js"></script> should work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question can help you with local local resources references [How to properly reference local resources in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in the same directory as your html the following should make it work :

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

If it's in a folder that is in the same directory as your HTML use:

```
<script src="FOLDERNAME/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

If it's a level above your HTML file use:

```
<script src="../jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

If none of these work be sure to double check your file's name in case there's a space in beginning or the end of the file's name.

**[EDIT]**

Well, if there's no spelling error and the change of placement doesn't fix it, then probably one or both of the files are corrupted. By the way, your jQuery version is outdated. Download v2.1.1 or use this script tag:

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The file is definitely in the same directory as the index.html file where it is referenced. However this still produces errors.

Comment: Be sure then to double-check for any spelling errors. You may as well just copy the filename straight from the file itself and paste it in your editor. If that doesn't work either, please edit your question with more info as to where you have placed your script tag, because that may be the problem.

Comment: Okay I added the html file and a picture of where the jquery file is placed

Comment: I tried that and it didn't change the 404 error on the JQuery file

Comment: Same error message unfortunately, is there an issue with the placement of the file?

Comment: Yes, your placement is incorrect. You should first include jQuery and then any other plugins that require it to work.

Comment: Did you download the new jQuery file and still nothing?

Comment: Yes I tried with multiple versions of the jquery file from their website, the same version the example was originally using, however I would like to make it available offline.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding that slash in front of the src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can access the jquery file by typing in the exact (local) URL into your browser.
Test by loading the URL `http://localhost:[port#]/jquery-1.11.1.js`
Alter this URL with the correct directory path for your dev environment until your jquery successfully loads.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I'm unaware of what you're describing

Comment: What he says is that you can use the absolute url of your file (link of the file inside server) instead of the relative url you are currently using (jquery.js).

Answer (score 0):

Paul try followings:

Verify jquery file name and path
if socket.io.js using jQuery change the order like

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

call javascript code after page load i.e. $(function(){}) as below:

```
$(function(){
var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was looking for the solution around. I found your question but I didn`t find the answer so I posted my own question here. Someone actually knew how to make it work. So if you still want to know just check the answer I got: [Raspberry Pi - Flask Server using JQuery not working Offline (Online it works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103458/raspberry-pi-flask-server-using-jquery-not-working-offline-online-it-works)

Comment: This is not an answer.