# use local gif file on a web page instead of an internet based gif

Tags: html, gif

I want to use a local file destination path instead of a url in this code so I don't have to be connected to the internet for it to fetch the gif. I've tried a few things across stack but nothing works.

```
<img src="gif url"alt=""style="width:12px;height:18px;">
```

Comment: try filesystem path, based on your OS. 
win - `<img src ="file:///C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\some.gif">`
unix replace src with - file:///home/user/Documents/some.gif

or if you have, start a web server  (this will perform better that file protocol) inside that path, and call files <img src="localhost:post/some.gif">

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html) should answer your question. Just need a path to the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

file://..../name.gif

or

http://localhost/.../name.gif
need local web server(iis or apache)