# Why don't the images don't show up on my ASP.Net core website?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an asp.net core web application and I want to add photos to it but when i try to debug it on IIS express, only the image icon shows up and I'm not quite sure what to do.
All of my images are jpg's and are in a folder inside of the wwwroot folder. This is how I reference the photos:

```
<img src="~/Images/picture.JPG" />
```

I am not sure what to do to make the photos show up.

Comment: Remove the `~`. Use `/Images/picture.jpg`. `/` Indicates to start on the root directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html `~` is used as alias on **server-side** (for Server.MapPath for example)

Comment: check that image is saved as picture.JPG or picture.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you allowing static files to be served:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

You can read more about it from here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html

Comment: Why is this even an option?

Comment: @SteveSmith by default you dont want to expose your server files, so you need to enable it

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you put your images in correct folder. In this case it should be:

```
C:\{project_folder}\wwwroot\images
```