# imported svg as img is not working

Tags: html, css, svg

Stumbled upon the following svg:

https://codepen.io/iliran11/pen/eRPxwG

While im copying the content of the pen into a file `liran.svg` there are the 2 following scenarios:

- opening directly `liran.svg` with latest chrome - it works perfectly
- Importing `liran.svg` to `index.html` (code below) - i can see nothing.

Maybe any exaplnation?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="./liran.svg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not import properly if it is the same folder with the `index.html` file use

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="liran.svg">
    </body>
</html>
```

If it is the parent folder of the folder containing `index.html` use

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="../liran.svg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Take a look a this link to learn more on referencing files in `html` and `css` [How to properly reference local resources in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html)

Comment: thanks, but still not working.  have you tried it on your own machine?

Comment: Where is the link to the svg you used?, because what i saw there was a base64 encoded svg, unless you converted it because copying that wont work

Comment: that's the svg i got. with base64 inside. you say that the browser can't handle this as imported `img`?

Comment: Yeah, use [base64decode](https://www.base64decode.org) to convert the base64 the normal svg code then try it again