# Adding src Dynamically to img in C#

Tags: c#, html, image

I have an `img` tag. 
(I am using just image and not asp.net because it is an `imageMap` that I have working with an `img`). 
I dynamically set the `src` as below in 3 different ways. The first way works and the image is included in the project. But when I try to add the `src` the 2nd way it fails to display the image. That image is not part of the project. I have even tried the 3rd way for a different location but it fails to load as well. It is not part of the project either. What I need to be able to do is load ans image `src` dynamically that is not included in the project and have it display.

```
<img runat="server" class="ImageMap" id="ImageMapID" src="" usemap="#imagemap" />

ImageMapID.Attributes["src"] = @"/Icons/XXXX XXXX.png";//first way that works

ImageMapID.Attributes["src"] = @"/documents/XXXXX/XXXX_04092017.pdf"; // second way that fails

ImageMapID.Attributes["src"] = @"file://C:/temp/XXXXXXXX.pdf";// third way that fails
```

Any ideas anybody? I should add they are different images but they should all work.

Comment: The PDF is a document, not an image.

Comment: Just use <embed> tag for embedded pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should know, PDF files are not image objects, so you can't use `img` tag to embed it. You need to use `iframe` tag instead:

```
<iframe src="file:///C:/temp/XXXXXXXX.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
   ...
</iframe>
```

Or use `embed`/`object` tag with same file path:

```
<embed src="file:///C:/temp/XXXXXXXX.pdf" width="600" height="400" type="application/pdf">

<object type="application/pdf" data="file:///C:/temp/XXXXXXXX.pdf" title="XXXXX" width="600" height="400" >...</object>
```

If you want to include local file path for images, use `file` reference path or relative path with proper directory structure shown in example below:

```
ImageMapID.Attributes["src"] = @"file:///C:/temp/Icons/XXXXXXXX.png";

// watch out for current relative path you're using
ImageMapID.Attributes["src"] = @"../../temp/Icons/XXXXXXXX.png";
```

Note that Windows local drive path uses this format to refer any files for use in any HTML elements with source attribute:

```
file:///[drive letter]:/[path_to_resource]/[filename].[extension]
```

References:

[How to properly reference local resources in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html)

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: I just changed the document to a jpeg. That solved my problem. The pdf was breaking my app. Thanks for the lesson. I now know that pdf is not an image object.