# Why can't I find a local file in my HTML?

Tags: android, html

I have the following really simple HTML - see below.

I have stored the HTML in a .html file on my PC and I have placed the PNG file in the same folder. When I open the HTML file, it works fine. However when I move the two files to my Android phone and execute the HTML file, the PNG file is not found (the not found icon is displayed). This happens with several browsers (including Chrome and Opera). This used to work. Any idea why I'm getting the error?

Has something changed recently? For example, when I open the above HTML file on my Android, I now see "content://" in the address line whereas I used to see "file://".

Many thanks

```
<BODY>
    <IMG src="./1419196262_circle_close_delete-20.png">
</BODY>
```

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14489018/2696626

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that this link helps. In general, I understand how to reference files in the same folder as my HTML file. It's recently on Android that problems have arisen.

The problem seems to be that various file managers no longer open the HTML file with a file:/// address. Rather they open it with a content:/// address.

If I manually type in a file:/// address into the address bar of an Android browser, I now see that it still works fine.

But when a content:/// address is used (because that's the address that the file managers use), file references are no longer found.