# Image not showing up in navigation bar? Website is not online yet, just in editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I go about making sure my images work? The images are not hosted and the website is not published yet, this is all just locally on my PC.

```
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="logo"><img src="Logo.png"</li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Active Chapter</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Philanthropy</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="items"><a href="#">Brothers Only</a></li>
        <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Is your image in the same folder as your HTML file? If it's not, you need to specify it's path, like <img src="/images/Logo.png"> if it is inside the images folder of your project.

Comment: If your pc is linux, make sure that the file name it points to is _exactly_ as it is: Unix file/directory names are case sensitive. In your case, if your file is named "logo.png", it would not be found.

Answer (score 2):

in this line

```
> <li class="logo"><img src="Logo.png"</li>
```

there is a mistake img tag is not closed .. it should closed like that 
second thing is in your case image should be in the same folder where your file is and name should be 100% same "case sensitive" Logo.png is not equal to logo.png , keep that in mind . image type should be same "png" "jpg" .
and in the last line of html you are using font-awesome class

```
> <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

to use this class you must have to add font-awesome cdn to use it

Comment: tags closed, file extensions match up, the image is showing but with that placeholder for if the image cannot load.

Comment: can you send me screenshot ? of what you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

Based on your snippet here Logo.png would have to be in the same folder as the HTML file. Here is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489016/how-to-properly-reference-local-resources-in-html) that explains how to point to your files properly.

Comment: It is in the same folder!